# Get actual object Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

I have two forms in my new view, one is for the product and the other is for fotos. 
When I upload the fotos with a select.file field, these are created by Ajax call by a file create.js.erb then when I fill the others fields to the product I've another button to create it. So I have two forms and one way to create each one.

The problem is the ID, the solution that I've found was to create an object before the user enter to the new view, so I have this code:

Product's controller:

```
def new
      @product = current_user.products.create
end
```

It creates an object nil, now I can create my Foto to that object, like this:

Painting's controller:

```
def create
   @product = Product.last
   @painting = @product.paintings.create(params[:painting])
end
```

The problem is the line "@product = Product.last", I know that it isn't the right solution, because when I try the edit action, and when I try to create new objects it goes to the last product and not to the actual edit product.

How can I find that current product at my new action???

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Building a new object (really showing the new form, since #new is a GET request and should not make destructive changes)

```
 def new
    @product = current_user.products.build
  end
```

Creating a new object

```
def create
  @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
  if @product.save
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Showing the Edit form for an object

```
def edit
  @product = current_user.products.find(params[:id])
end
```

Updating an existing product

```
def update
  @product = current_user.products.find(params[:id])
  if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
    redirect_to @product
  else
     render :edit
  end
end
```

You'll notice that the GET requests (new and edit) make no chagnes to the database.

The two destructive requests (PUT and POST) to (update/create) make changes to the database.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, at my new view I have two forms, one for the product and another one for paintings, so when I upload paintings with a file.field field I create the paintings by an Ajax request to show it at that "new view". How can I associate those new paintings with the current product object??? thanks a lot.

Comment: You are now talking about nested resources (since paintings belong to a product). Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources and http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources

Comment: Hi Jesse, but in my project I have two forms in the same view, please take a look at gist.github.com/3982996, thanks.

Comment: @JulioAhuactzin my recommendations stand --- possibly simplify your question into something relatable and readable.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in general is awkward and probably not the best way to use the new action of a controller.

To answer your question you would need to pass in the ID of the product in your parameters.

Depending how you are submitting your paintings form you need to add the parameter in either the body of the request or the url. that way you would be able to do something like

**Painting's controller**

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id]
  @painting = @product.paintings.create(params[:painting])
end
```

If you add a code snippet of your views/forms I'll probably be able to help you better.

Comment: I've tried that, but it brings an error log like: Couldn't find Product without an ID. When I'm in my new view there is already an empty object like this: [["color", nil], ["created_at", Tue, 30 Oct 2012 20:36:11 UTC +00:00], ["description", nil], ["material", nil], ["picture", nil], ["quantity", nil], ["refund_policy", nil], ["size", nil], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 30 Oct 2012 20:36:11 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 2]], It has and user_id and Product.id, I would like to use that Product.id in my Painting's controller.

Comment: I can't help you without viewing a bit of your view's code. What exactly is your workflow with the product and painting model? You create a product and then add a painting? What you could do is instead of calling a Painting controller to create the product's painting, just create it in the create action of your product's painting.

Comment: When you are in the new view, there is a form for the product and a select.field field to add the paintings, so when you upload the fotos, these are automatically created by an Ajax request, So I need to add and ID for those objects, that's why I think that I can create and object before with nil parameters and the add the paintings to that object.

Comment: Again, I'd need to see your view's code if you want me to help you further